# REACT JS dynamic meta tags after receiving response

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In REACT JS, I'm using SSR. I want to change meta description dynamically after receiving response at my video page. Is it possible to change meta after receiving response from database in my video page???

Comment: Please, provide your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you have tried and where it has gone wrong in order to assist us to help you (and the wider community)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking, it is important to provide enough details to help diagnosing the problem. You should provide at least a short (but not too short) piece of code related to what you are asking. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I'm using react-helmet package to set that. I'm checking for the response and as I'm getting the response I just setting title and description from my response for that perticular page and it's totally dynamic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control this, you need to hold the page from rendering before you get that database response. I think that your only bet is to do some server side rendering [SSR & React 16](https://hackernoon.com/whats-new-with-server-side-rendering-in-react-16-9b0d78585d67)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to pass my metadata through SSR? I mean after getting response in the server how to pass that response data as a metadata?